# Exporting NetCDF layer with defined colors using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, netcdf

I have average wind speed NetCDF file (.nc) that I imported to QGIS. Then I defined colors for wind speeds in equal interval (3, 3.5, 4, 4.5 etc). Now I would like to save this colored map for sharing purpose. When exporting and saving as GeoTiff, the colors change to black and white.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select:

1. Right-Click and Export
2. Save As...
3. Rendered image (click in checkbox) - This allow you have the style in your GeoTiff image.

[image]

4. Click ok

With this process, your will save the colors in your image.